# Duplicate android app?

Tags: android, ios, duplicates

I have made an App for iOS and Android using Adobe Flash AIR, and I want to duplicate this app because only the contents inside are change. Do I have to change Certificate? About iOS Do I have to change Certificate and Provision Profile too? Thank for answering.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate the android app, and publish a new one, you will need to change the package name. This will allow you to have both apps installed side by side, and you can upload the new one to google play. 
It's also a good idea to sign with a new certificate, but not required.

Comment: And for iOS you need a new distribution provisioning profile. You can keep the same certificate as long as it is not expired.

Comment: Also, obviously, you need new bundle IDs for iOS (and probably Android as well)